# AJAX showing error message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have one form ,when i click submit button am saving those values and on button click am calling "SaveData() " method.

So when i try to add data and click on submit button and nothing is happening am getting following errors in my browser log.

My onclick function code

```
function requestReferral() {
var nameperson = $("#namefield").val();
var contact1 = $("#contact").val();
  //Till this part working  i mean alert is printing .
        $.ajax({
             url: '/mycontroller/myfunction',
             data: 'name='+nameperson+'&contact='+contact1,
               type: 'post',
                success: function(result){
               data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
                if(data.result == "SUCCESS"){
                        clearMyFormData();

                } else {
                       showMessage();
                }
        }
});

}
```

my error is

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)    with my controller url   `www.example.com/mycontroller/myfunction`

Comment: If you're getting an internal server error, posting the code for the ajax call probably isn't going to help much ?

Comment: 1. your url could be wrong
2. look in your server logs, maybe your backend script is throwing an error

Comment: 500 is  self explanatory

Comment: You have to url-encode data you send with request. Since you use jquery you can use its `serialize()` method for this.

Comment: And what happens if you access `domain.com/mycontroller/myfunction` directly? Presuming that's your actual path...?

Comment: reason was my db dnt have one table for this

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check if your url is ok, for example, if you are using php with codeigniter your url need to be like this:

```
url: <?php echo base_url()?>mycontroller/myfunction
```

and second, when I used ajax, I send data like this

```
    postData = {
        name: nameperson,
        contact: contact1
    }

     $.ajax({
         url: '/mycontroller/myfunction',
         data: postData
           type: 'post',
            success: function(result){
           data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            if(data.result == "SUCCESS"){
                    clearMyFormData();

            } else {
                   showMessage();
            }
    }
```